# What's a short phrase meaning "visited and ascended" (e.g. a tower)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a short and clear word or phrase, that is not pretentious-sounding, meaning "visited and ascended", as in buildings, e.g. Bert visited the lobby of Empire State Building, but Ernie went up to the observation deck?

> Ernie ***_*__*_*____** the Empire State Building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will `Ernie went to the top of Empire State Building` serve your purpose?

Comment: If I go straight to the top of the Empire State Building, then I don't visit it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: But most [ESB visitors](http://www.esbnyc.com/tourism.asp) go straight to the top.

Comment: @Callithumpian - [That approach has its dangers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_kong)

Comment: @Callithumpian That is not visiting the tower, though. It would be like if I say I visited a museum, and I just went to the restrooms.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the term is "climbed", as in

> Ernie climbed the Empire State Building.

This can be seen by the fact that people also climb tourist sites i.e."We went to KL and climbed the Twin Towers," or "Jack and Henry climbed Shoreman's Mountain", meaning to say, they visited and went up these sites.

Answer (score 2):

I think your initial suggestion was perfectly acceptable

> Ernie ascended the Empire State Building

alternatively you could use

> Ernie scaled the Empire State Building

Answer (score 1):

How about "we went up the tower"?

Answer (score 1):

Ernie **climbed up** the tower